# SQL UPDATE Not Updating

Tags: mysql, database

After uploading a csv file, I am trying to insert its contents into my database table. I have this query:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("dbtest",$connect);

//get the file 
$handle = fopen($filename,"r");

do { 
    if (isset($data[0])) { 
        $data0  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]);  //rcode
        $data1  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]);  //pcode
        $data2  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]);  //mcode
        $data3  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]);  //bcode
        $data4  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]);  //ecode
        $data5  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[5]);  //filetype
        $data6  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[6]);  //rec_count
        $data7  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[7]);  //gen_count
        $data8  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[8]);  //qc_count
        $data9  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[9]);  //be_count
        $data10 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[10]); //trn_count

$query = "INSERT INTO tbltest(rcode,pcode,mcode,bcode,ecode,filetype,rec_count,
          gen_count,qc_count,be_count,trn_count) VALUES ('$data0','$data1','$data2',
          '$data3', '$data4', '$data5', '$data6', '$data7', '$data8', '$data9', '$data10') 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rec_count=values(rec_count),gen_count=values(gen_count),
          qc_count=values(qc_count), be_count=values(be_count), trn_count=values(trn_count)";

mysql_query ($query,$connect) ;
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"|"));
```

And it's working neatly but then as the database was re-structured, I just then need to update the database table as `rcode to filetype` has values already and I just need to insert values of `rec_count to trn_count`. So my first query `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` has been change to `UPDATE` only. And so I did this:

```
$query = "UPDATE tbltest SET (rec_count='$data6', gen_count = '$data7', 
          qc_count = '$data8', be_count = '$data9', trn_count= '$data10') WHERE 
          (rcode = '$data0', pcode = '$data1', mcode = '$data2', bcode = '$data3', 
          ecode = '$data4', filetype = '$data5')";
```

My problem now is that, my `UPDATE` seems to be not working as it doesn't update the database table. Bu when I did this;

```
$query = "UPDATE tbltest SET rcode = '5'";
```

The database is being updated. When I tried `echo $query;`, the echo responds the correct data (from the csv). I just cannot figure why it doesn't insert these data into the database. Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect. The statement should read something like

```
UPDATE tbltest
SET rec_count='...', gen_count = '...', ... 
WHERE rcode = '...' AND pcode = '...' AND ...
```

See [MySQL UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: Doing that now, I'll be updating later. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer.